# Displaying state list in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some simple code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    letters: ["a", "b", "c"]
  };

  addLetter = () => {
    const { letters } = this.state;
    letters.push("d");
    this.setState({ letters });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addLetter}>Click to add a letter</button>
        <h1>letters: {this.state.letters}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1lqw338mw).

When I click the button, the letter `'d'` should be added to the `letters` in state. This works as intended. However, the letters do not update on the page as one would expect when state changes.

It's worth noting that:

```
<h1>letters: {this.state.letters.reduce((a, l) => a + l, "")}</h1>
```

or:

```
<h1>letters: {this.state.letters.toString()}</h1>
```

do update the page as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: My mistake was I thought `const { letters } = this.state;` copied `letters`, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: beware of deep vs shallow copies; what you have there is imho shallow copy of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the letter's state (the array), instead of mutating it ([working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2q2vwkl5w)). According to the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly): Do Not Modify State Directly.

When you're converting the array to a string, the current string is different from the previous string because strings are immutable. The array however stays the same array even if you add another item to it.

**Example:**

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const strA = a.toString();
a.push(4);
const strB = a.toString();

console.log(a === a); // true
console.log(strA === strB); // false
```

**Solution:** create a new array from the old one.

```
addLetter = () => {
  const { letters } = this.state;
  this.setState({ letters: [...letters, 'd'] });
};
```

Comment: Working example doesn't seem to have your code on my end. It seems the state is setting fine, if you `console.log()` it though?

Comment: Fixed the working example. The state is mutating, but react doesn't detect the change because you haven't replace it.

Comment: Why is it not replaced? And why does it work when doing e.g. `this.state.letters.toString()`?

Comment: Because the current string is not the same as the previous string. The reference to the array is the same, although you've changed the content by pushing a value.

Comment: Ah, so I should do: `const { letters } = {...this.state};` in future, right?

Comment: not sure I understand your explanation. Can you clarify?

Comment: Nope. Because this will replace the wrapping object, but not letters.

Comment: `const { letters } = {...this.state}; letters.push("d"); this.setState({ letters });` works as intended.

Comment: Because stringA is different than stringB, while arrayA is the same as arrayA even if you add another item to it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Can you add that to your answer? That's the real answer I was looking for.

Comment: Added plus an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have got an answer though. Would like to explain it a bit further.

You are basically not changing the state ever. And react only detects the changes in state. Now tricky part is that you might be thinking that you are updating the array object and hence changing the state but that's not true. The original array reference is never changed in state and hence no change. So, to solve this in es6 you could use ... operator as follows in your addLetter declaration.

```
addLetter = () => {
    const { letters } = this.state;
    letters.push("d");
    this.setState({ letters:[...letters] });
  };
```

`...` operator basically clones the original object and is a short hand operator from `es6`.

You could use clone method as well e.g. [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've forked and fixed your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ywnmr47q8z

1) You have to mutate the new state

2) you have to call `.join("")` to build string from array. now it is working

[image: Edit ywnmr47q8z]

Comment: Why does: `const newLetters = letters;` and then `push()` work different to: `letters.push()`?

Comment: It doesn't it is same, I just wrote it differently to illustrate it. your code is valid in handler